# Using matrix.mapPoints(). I want to convert screen coordinate into a matrix point of an Imageview. Any suggestions?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, imageview, ondraw

So I have a custom ImageView on screen,**on which scale and move gestures are applied using matrix transformation**. There's a red marker like imageview exactly at the center of the custom Imageview **(look at the screenshot attached)**. 
Now when I press the 'Add checkpoint' button, a green dot should appear on the canvas exactly below the marker like imageview, and should stick with imageview and move along when I scale or move the image. I did that using matrix.mapPoints().
**The problem is that the point is not appearing exactly below the marker,
even though I passed the marker imageview's coordinates to the mapPoints() function.**

onClick for 'Add CheckPoint' button -

```
 checkpointBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            iv.drawRect = true;
            iv.x = marker_iv.getX();  //marker_iv is red marker imageview
            iv.y = marker_iv.getY();
            iv.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

Custom ImageView class -

```
public class DrawImageView extends ImageView {

private Paint currentPaint;
public boolean drawRect = false;
public float x;
public float y;
public Bitmap newBitmap;
public Matrix matrix;


public DrawImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    currentPaint = new Paint();
    currentPaint.setDither(true);
    currentPaint.setColor(0xFF00CC00);
    currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(60);
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (drawRect) {



        float[] pts = {x, y};
        Matrix matrix = this.getImageMatrix();
        matrix.mapPoints(pts);
        System.out.println("Rushi : NewPoint : " + pts[0] + "," + pts[1]);
        canvas.drawPoint(pts[0], pts[1], currentPaint);
    }
}
```

}

[image: As you can see, the green dot doesn't appear right below the red marker]

Comment: I shifted the code to onTouch() with MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN. It works brilliantly!!!!!! The points are moving with the image. Now i will try to integrate this in my code.

Comment: In my XML, I added your class. In MainActivity.class, I added setContentView(R.layout.activity_main). The scaling and moving works but the onTouch() is not called. What can be wrong?

Comment: `onTouchEvent`, not `onTouch` - this is `View#onTouchEvent()` method

Comment: I fixed it. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please check out my latest question. It's related to image storage.